# JQUERY Multiple IF Conditions

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply multiple conditions to this validateForm function to make certain form fields non mandatory. The if condition 
 `if ((y[i].value == "" && y[i].name!="phone"))`

works fine to make a single field non mandatory, but when I apply multiple conditions to make multiple fields non mandatory such as;

```
if ((y[i].value == "" && y[i].name!="phone") || (y[i].value == "" && y[i].name!="yyyy")){

// add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;

}
```

It doesnt seem to work. All the fields becomes mandatory again. What am I doing wrong please?

The full code was copied from W3Schools as below:

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "" && y[i].name!="phone") 
    {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;

    }

  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}




function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more code. Would be awesome if you could use the Snippet function here to provide a reproducible example that we can use to play around

Comment: Regardless of the cause, you could use the `required` attribute instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```js
const criteriaOptions = ["phone", "yyyy"]

if (y[i].value == "" && !criteriaOptions.includes(y[i].name)) {

// add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;

}
```